# sum the difference of timestamps for a month

Tags: php, laravel

want to sum the daily working hours of a user and i have the time for checkin and checkout in a time column

```
$sql=" SELECT User_id, date, min(time) AS checkedin, max(time) AS checkedout,( (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(max(time), min(time))) / 60) / 60) difference
            FROM profile WHERE 1 GROUP BY User_id, date";
            $previousdata = DB::select($sql);
```

i get this array from the sql query that i have used and i want to add the difference that i get for everyday for a month's data.
not to worry abt the date format, i am from nepal and am using the nepali date.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [User_id] => 1
            [date] => 2076-02-06
            [checkedin] => 12:11:40
            [checkedout] => 19:11:43
            [difference] => 7.00083333
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [User_id] => 1
            [date] => 2076-02-08
            [checkedin] => 12:15:40
            [checkedout] => 15:15:48
            [difference] => 3.00222222
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
array_sum(array_column($arr,'difference'));
```

To get total working hours.

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/AefCK).

Comment: used this and worked fine $wsum=0;
             foreach($previousdata as $key=>$value){
                 $dbresponse[$value->difference] = !empty($value->sum)?$value->sum:0;
                 $wsum += $value->difference;
             }

Comment: *Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with query then use [`rollup`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-rollup/)

```
SELECT User_id, date, min(time) AS checkedin, max(time) AS checkedout,( (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(max(time), min(time))) / 60) / 60) difference
FROM profile WHERE 1 GROUP BY User_id, date WITH ROLLUP";
```

But it will add additional rows after each group to show the sum of them and one at the bottom of result-set for overall sum.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help